# Return a value in Google sheet

Tags: google-sheets

Here is the table I have:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWm48.png

The color pink is number as 1 and green is number as 2.

So I want whenever I color pink or green, I want the air (D column) to get the result from rows 3 matches with the day. For example, when cell T19 is colored then in the Air cell will return value as 4.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: It would be easier for us to test your data if you can provide a sample spreadsheet. See [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Sure thing, here is the table link https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1S4LblIxTZgrZF9BSo55e1MGEZpIKi8iarQeTDPyZGyc/edit?usp=sharing
As I mentioned above, I want to get value of the date in Air (column D) when I put 1 or 2 from g2:az2 etc.

Answer (score 1):

Since we need to detect color changes in Sheets, you need to use Apps Script with Installable Trigger of onChange.

Try this:

1. Create a script, go to **Extensions -> Apps Script** or **Tools -> Apps Script** for old versions.
2. Delete the content of Code.gs, paste the code provided below and save.
3. Setup the onChange Installable Trigger (See setup instructions below)
4. In your Sheet, paste this formula that will automatically populate the column **Deliver** if **Air** column has data. `=ArrayFormula(IF(D4:D <> "", D4:D-1, ""))`

**Code:**

```
function onChange(e){
  var activeRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  var row = activeRange.getRow();
  var col = activeRange.getColumn();
  var color = activeRange.getBackground();
  var green = "#b7e1cd"; //change this hex color code base on the color you are using
  var pink = "#ffd4d4"; //change this hex color code base on the color you are using
  var validRange = activeRange.getSheet().getName() == "Sheet1" && activeRange.getNumColumns() == 1 && activeRange.getNumRows() == 1;
  if(row > 3 && col > 6 && validRange && (color == green || color == pink)){
    var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var date = sh.getRange(2, col).getValue();
    sh.getRange(row, 4).setValue(date);
  }
}
```

*Note: Make sure that the hex color in the code is the same hex color in the Sheets*

**How to setup onChange Installable Trigger:**

1. In the left menu of your Apps Script, Go to the **Triggers** Tab.
2. Click **Add Trigger**.
3. Copy the setup provided in the screenshot below.
4. Click **Save**.

[image]

Once the setup are done, you are now ready to go.

**Demo:**

[image]

### References:

- [Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet)
- [Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range)
- [Installable Trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)
- [Event Object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)